# User in group with r/w access does not actually get the read/write anything

Tags: linux, chmod, chown, user-permissions, chgrp

I added my user to the www-data group.
I chmodded a certain directory to 774 (-R, recursively) so only the owner and the group can change something.

Yet my user can't even access it. What am I missing?
Here's my `ls -alh` output:

```
drwxrwxr-- 13 www-data www-data 4,0K 2011-03-28 23:10 mydir
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- What does `id -a` return? You may need to start a new shell or run `newgrp`, since your existing shells will not automatically get the new group permissions.
- 774 permissions will probably not do what you want. I suspect you want 775. Without execute permissions, other users will not be able to search the directory.

Comment: The old "logout" "login" procedure. :-)

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is that the upper directory doesn't have permissions correctly set.